# Find digits and sum them in a google spreadsheet column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets with a column that can contains text like this:

```
+-----------------+
| running, 3.4 km |
+-----------------+
|                 |
+-----------------+
|                 |
+-----------------+
| running, 5.2 km |
+-----------------+
| running, 4.7 km |
+-----------------+
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

How can I search through this column and get the sum of the digits? (here 3.4+5.2+4.7)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or all in one go:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(A2:A,"[0-9\.]+")+0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your example is in column A, then you can use the `SPLIT()` function or the `REGEXEXTRACT()` function.

**Example 1:** Using `SPLIT()`:

```
           A                 B             B        C    D
  +-----------------+-----------------+----------+-----+----+
1 | running, 3.4 km | =SPLIT(A1, " ") | running, | 3.4 | km |
  +-----------------+-----------------+----------+-----+----+
```

Then use `SUM()` on column `C`.

**Example 2:** Using `REGEXEXTRACT()`:

```
           A                        B                  B   
  +-----------------+-------------------------------+-----+
1 | running, 3.4 km | =REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d*.\.\d") | 3.4 |
  +-----------------+-------------------------------+-----+
```

Then use `SUM()` on column `B`.